# facebook - recover from CLOSE_LOGIN_FAILED when user hits cancel button

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, permissions

In my app when the user hits the facebook login button, facebook displays a page asking him to confirm permissions - I specifically ask for the email permission in addition to the public_profile. If the user hits "cancel" and exits back to the main page then the session state becomes CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED. If the user then hits the facebook login button again, the permissions page is displayed again, but this time it only shows "public_profile". How can I make it ask for email even when the session state was CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED?

Here is my code:

```
if(!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(context).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")));
    } 
    else {
        Session.openActiveSession(context, true, statusCallback);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved with the following code:

```
        if (session.isOpened()) {
        Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, statusCallback);
    } else if(session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED)) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(READ_PERMISSIONS));
    }
    else { //deal with CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED and all other session types
        session = new Session(activity);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(READ_PERMISSIONS));
    }
```